# Unable to make HTTP call with keycloak (v24.0.1) - Angular 17+

Tags: angular, http, keycloak

I am using Angular 17 and keycloak.js version 24.0.1. I am trying to refresh token with the api call after checking if token is valid or not. Here is

Keycloak.js -

```
    static auth: any = {};

    static init(): Promise<any> {
        const keycloakAuth = new Keycloak({
            url: environment.keycloakRootUrl,
            realm: 'master',
            clientId: 'axelt',
            // 'ssl-required': 'external',
            // 'public-client': true
        });

        KeycloakService.auth.loggedIn = false;

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            keycloakAuth.init({ onLoad: 'check-sso', checkLoginIframe: false })
                .then(() => {
                    if (keycloakAuth.authenticated) {
                        sessionStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(keycloakAuth.token));
                        KeycloakService.auth.loggedIn = true;
                        KeycloakService.auth.authz = keycloakAuth;
                        KeycloakService.auth.logoutUrl = keycloakAuth.authServerUrl
                            + 'realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri='
                            + document.baseURI
                            + '&id_token_hint='
                            + keycloakAuth.idToken
                        // + 'realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/logout';
                    }
                    resolve(keycloakAuth.authenticated);
                }, () => {
                    reject();
                })
        });
    }

    getToken(): Promise<string> {
        return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
            debugger
            if (KeycloakService.auth.authz.token) {
                KeycloakService.auth.authz
                    .updateToken(5)
                    .success(() => {
                        resolve(<string>KeycloakService.auth.authz.token);
                    })
                    .error(() => {
                        window.location.reload();
                        reject('Failed to refresh token');
                    });
            } else {
                reject('Not logged in');
            }
        });
    }

    getKeyCloakTokenAsObservable(): Observable<any> {
        const tokenPromise: Promise<string> = this.getToken();
        return fromPromise(tokenPromise).pipe(
            tap(token => {                
                console.log('token --> ', token)
                sessionStorage.setItem("token", JSON.stringify(token))
            })
        );
    }
```

and this is my appInit method inside appService

```
    appInit() {
        return new Promise<void>((resolve: any, reject) => {
            this.http.get<User>(environment.generic.getRole).subscribe((resp: any) => {
                if (resp.userId && resp.modules.length && resp.roleName) {
                this.USERNAME = resp.userId.split('@')[0] || '';
                this.userService.setUserAccessData = resp;
                resolve();
                return;
                } else {
                    this.router.navigate(['/errorlogin']);
                    reject();
                }
            }, (error) => {
                this.router.navigate(['/errorlogin']);
                reject();
            })
            // });
        }).catch(error => {
            // Code Goes here
            this.router.navigate(['/errorlogin']);
        })
    }
```

and I am wrapping my GET call like this

```
  get<T>(url: string, params?: HttpParams) {
    // return this.http.get<T>(url, {params})
    return this.keycloakService.getKeyCloakTokenAsObservable().pipe(
      mergeMap(token => this.http.get<T>(url, { params }))
    );
  }
...Other methods are also the same...
```

When i am using Keycloak version **20.0.1** everything works as expected and i am able to access the pages and stuff but after i upgraded to keycloak version **24.0.1** the code goes into the CATCH block inside appInit and navigates to errorLogin. Consoled the error and its undefined.

if i call the GET method like - return this.http.get(url, {params}), without wrapping it, that also works but token does not get refreshed.

Am i missing something or doing something wrong, any help would be appreciated.

P.s The keycloak file was created before i started working on the project, most probably, in January or starting feb.

Comment: are you using the latest keycloak.js for version 24? that could be the promlem.
btw `appInit` in appInitService can just return an observable. There is no need to transform it into a promise. It's a lot of code for nothing...
you should not subscribe but instead just return the observable. Use `.pipe(map(resp => { YOUR CODE HERE...}))`   you can then `throw new Error("my error")` inside the `map()`